# Using Java, how to determine the outbound service calls from a tomcat webserver?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Basically, I want to determine/log all the outbound service calls happening from our Spring application for a given request.

I would like to figure out all the REST/HTTP calls being made from our application.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Using AOP maintain counters

Comment: Can you give a code sample of an outgoing call (with the imports) so we can see which http client library you use. Many libs have a loglevel to see what's happening. httpclient for example has a wire trace feature which can be used for this.

Comment: How the calls are made? spring or cxf or which framework you are using?

Comment: Its a huge application and many modules with in the application make an external call. So, we want to introduce policing of the external calls. Presently it is not even known... It is a Spring application running on tomcat

Comment: The application uses different client libraries for accessing external services, based on vendor. Few calls are made using apache http-connection-manager and others use custom clients provided by vendors.

Comment: With wireshark, you could trace all the outbound calls for a typical use of your application. If you want to enumerate ALL the possible calls, I'm afraid you'd have to dig into the source code of your app

Answer (score 0):

Configure the JVM to use a proxy, and then completely block outgoing connections that don't go to the proxy. Then, (wait for it), watch everything that goes through the proxy.